# Browser for mobile application? Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In mobile application, in asp.net i developed one mobile application, now i want to run the application is there any seperat browser to test the application.

[image]

where i can get this browsers, please help me thank you.

```
   ![enter image description here][2]


  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u27C7.jpg
```

Comment: for iphone 
http://www.testiphone.com/
 for windows
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402563%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: when i run the mobile form with emulator 1.0 i got the error i upload the screen shot.

Answer (score 2):

Install the `Windows Phone 7 Emulator`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402563(v=vs.92).aspx

Or any other mobile browser emulator that your application needs to support. Though, nothing beats the real thing...

Comment: Mr. Xander, i downloaded and installed, but when i select browse with i am not getting any mobile browser can you help me

Comment: please find out the error, what i got when adding the emulator 1.0 and ru the application.

Comment: you need to copy the `url` of your web application and put it in the mobile browser...